# Cannot connect to an Hana database via its ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, sap-hana

I have not found any documentation about *ODBC* connection strings for *Hana* and am trying to connect using the [examples](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.00/en-US/66a4169b84b2466892e1af9781049836.html) in *SAP HANA Database Client Interfaces*.

An attempt to connect via *ODBC* with the connection string:

```
DRIVER=HDBODBC; SERVERNODE=192.168.0.213:30015; ID=SYSTEM; PWD=PASSWORD;
```

fails with this error:

```
ERROR [08S01] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC]
Communication link failure;
-10709 Connection failed (RTE:[0]  (192.168.0.213:30015))
```

whereas the corresponding *ADO.NET* connection works:

```
Server=192.168.0.213:30015;UserName=SYSTEM;Password=PASSWORD;
```

What may be wrong with the *ODBC* connection? I have the correct driver installed.

Answer (score -1):

you might require to install [SAP HANA Database Client for ODBC configuration](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/connect-sap-hana-database-from-sql-server-with-linked-server-using-odbc-connection.aspx)

Please refer to above linked document for a sample case where HDBODBC is installed for connection to HANA database via ODBC

After HDBODBC configuration is created as illustrated in referenced tutorial, you can build your connection string as follows referencing the System DSN name with DSN argument

"DSN=KodyazHANADb;SERVERNODE=myhdb.kodyaz.sap.biz:30815;UID=A00011462;PWD=myPassword+;DATABASENAME=K0D"

You can find the database name in SAP HANA Studio connection properties or by querying M_Databases system view